# Creating "listicles" via wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Are there any suggestions for wordpress plugins that create lists of images, similar to buzzfeed's community page editor?

The only reasonable one seemed to be here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/listly/

However, it is not native to wordpress / requires creating using their service

Answer (score 0):

@user749798

This post is old but as it is appearing in google results and no other alternative with this ease is present so I found a plugin here which will do exactly what you want to do without relying on listly services.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-nextpage/